# Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 system with Active Directory installed on it and using this computer for local development (Microsoft SharePoint).

What i wanted to do is to open the local Internet Explorer on this machine to run as a different user. I have created a simple user in the AD and i am not able to run as this user the Internet Explorer. I always get the following error message when i try to start it with the credentials of the new user:

`Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer`

Has someone an idea why this happens?

PS: Adding the users to the `Administrators` group is not an option ...

Answer (score 2):

It means what it says and says what it means. Standard users can not normally and *should* not normally log on to the desktop of an Active Directory Domain Controller.

You will need to create a group policy that allows users to 'log on locally' (IIRC, disables "Deny log on locally) for DCs and apply it to the user.

The better approach is to not use a DC as your desktop. If you need a DC for development, run it as a virtual guest on a standard workstation in hyperv and use the standard workstation (or another hyperv guest if you need a workstation to be a domain member) for your dev users.